# Question on the sign of following two functions

Tags: real-analysis

Sometime ago, I was browsing through the internet and I found an interesting question in AoPS (for the original post see [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1251300p6447057)). For the sake of completeness I post the question here,

> Let $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$. Define, $$f_\varepsilon(n)=\left(\dfrac{1-\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}\right)\left(\dfrac{n^2}{\ln \left(n^2\right)}+\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\ln \left((n+1)^2\right)}\right)-\left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{\ln \left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{2}\right)}\right)$$$$g_\varepsilon(n)=\left(\dfrac{1+\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}\right)\left(\dfrac{n^2}{\ln \left(n^2\right)}+\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\ln \left((n+1)^2\right)}\right)-\left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{\ln \left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{2}\right)}\right)$$ for all $n\ge 2$. Does there exists any $\varepsilon$ in the said interval such that for all sufficiently large $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the sign of either of the functions $f_\varepsilon$ and $g_\varepsilon$ remains same?

I tried to do this by differentiating $f'\varepsilon$ and $g'_{\varepsilon}$ but it got so messy that I couldn't conclude anything from it. Is there any way to solve it without differentiating $f_\varepsilon$ and $g_\varepsilon$?

Comment: I think the question is not posed well.  The two large parenthesized items are very close to each other.  For $\varepsilon=\frac 12$, for example, we will have $f_\varepsilon(n)=\frac 13() -() \lt 0$ and $g_\varepsilon(n)=3() -() \gt 0$.  I think you mean to ask if given any $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ we can find an $n$ such that ... This is equivalent to asking whether the ratio of the two parenthesized terms goes to $1$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your reluctance to differentiate is due the great mess you get. But consider $h(x)=x/\log x.$ It is easily seen that $h''(x)<0$ for all sufficiently large $x.$  So for all large $n$ we have  $$h(n^2)+h((n+1)^2)<2 h((n^2+(n+1)^2)/2,$$ and therefore for large $n,$ $$ \bullet \quad f_{\epsilon}(n)<0.$$ On the other hand, for large $x$ we have $h'(x)>0$ and $h'$ decreasing. So for large $n$,$$0<V(n)=h((n^2+(n+1)^2)/2)-h(n^2)<h'(n^2)((n^2+(n+1)^2)/2-n^2).$$ We can calculate from this, that $$0=\lim_{n\to \infty} V(n)/h(n)$$   From this, and with $h$ increasing and $h(n)\to \infty,$ we conclude that with  $$W(n)= \frac {2 h((n^2+(n+1)^2)/2)}{h(n^2)+h((n+1)^2)}=1,$$ we have $W(n)<1$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} W(n)=1.$$ Therefore for large $n,$ $$\bullet \quad g_{\epsilon}(n)>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure of what is meant by 'the sign of either of the functions remains same' but the following might give you a hint:

The function $a(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}$ is concave for sufficiently large $x$.We know that 
$\displaystyle f_{\epsilon},g_{\epsilon}=\lambda \left[a(x_1)+a(x_2)\right]-2a\left(\frac{x_1 +x_2}{2}\right)$

where $x_1=n^2, \ x_2=(n+1)^2$ and $\displaystyle \lambda=\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ or $\displaystyle \frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$.

From Jensen's inequality, this is negative when $\lambda\leq 1$ and hence $f_{\epsilon}<0$ for sufficiently large $n$.

[EDIT]

For any $\epsilon>0$, $g_{\epsilon}>0$ for sufficiently large $n$.To prove this, let $h=2a\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\right)-a(x_1)-a(x_2)$ and rewrite $g_{\epsilon}$ as $g_{\epsilon}=(\lambda-1)(a(x_1)+a(x_2))-h$. It suffices to show that $a(x_1)+a(x_2)$ has a faster growth rate than $h(x_1,x_2)$.

$a(x_1)+a(x_2)$ grows at least as fast as $O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log n^2}\right)=O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log n}\right)$. If you stare at it long enough it should be apparent that, for sufficiently large $n$, $h(x_1,x_2)<2(a(x_2)-a(x_1))=\frac{(n+1)^2}{\log (n+1)^2}-\frac{n^2}{\log n^2} <\frac{(n+1)^2-n^2}{\log (n+1)^2}<\frac{2n+1}{\log n^2}=O\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$.

Comment: Can anything be concluded about $g_\varepsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I think you are really asking if 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n^2}{\ln \left(n^2\right)}+\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\ln \left((n+1)^2\right)}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{\ln \left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{2}\right)}\right)}=1$$
We want to divide out $\frac {n^2}{\ln (n^2)}$ so note that $$\frac {(n+1)^2}{n^2}=1+\frac 2n + \frac 1{n^2}\\\frac {\ln((n+1)^2)}{\ln (n^2)}=\frac {\ln (n+1)}{\ln n}\approx 1+\frac 1{n \ln \frac 1n}\\
\dfrac{\ln \left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{2}\right)}{\log(n^2)}\approx 1+\frac 1{2n \ln \frac 1n}$$ And the $\frac 1n$ order terms do not cancel.  We can write 
$$\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{n^2}{\ln \left(n^2\right)}+\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{\ln \left((n+1)^2\right)}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{\ln \left(\dfrac{n^2+(n+1)^2}{2}\right)}\right)}\approx \dfrac {\left(\dfrac{1+1+\frac 2n}{1+\frac 1{n\log \dfrac 1n}}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{1+1+\frac 2n}{1+\frac 1{2n\log \dfrac 1n}}\right)}\approx 1+\frac 1{2n \ln \frac 1n}\to 1$$